# How to disable subscription notification on startup of Meteor.js?

Tags: meteor

Start notification:

```
** You've set up some data subscriptions with Meteor.publish()
```

How to disable?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Just a heads up that this question doesn't meet the quality guidelines of SO because it's unclear, and doesn't show an effort to solve the issue yourself. For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). 
I've answered anyway as a gesture of goodwill, but be aware that other SO users may downvote questions like this. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you're getting this whole error message:

```
** You've set up some data subscriptions with Meteor.publish(), but
** you still have autopublish turned on. Because autopublish is still
** on, your Meteor.publish() calls won't have much effect. All data
** will still be sent to all clients.
**
** Turn off autopublish by removing the autopublish package:
**
**   $ meteor remove autopublish
**
** .. and make sure you have Meteor.publish() and Meteor.subscribe() calls
** for each collection that you want clients to see.
```

To make the notification go away, just do what it asks you to do and run:

```
meteor remove autopublish
```

---

### What is `autopublish`?

Autopublish is a package used for rapid prototyping. It sends all collections from MongoDB to the client for easy use. From the docs:

> Publish all server collections to the client. This package is useful for prototyping an app without worrying about which clients have access to certain data, but should be removed as soon as the app needs to restrict which data is seen by the client.

Before putting your app on the internet you will want to turn this off and use publications and subscriptions to secure, filter and mange your data flow